# How to extract data from javascript in a json format?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am getting a hardtime extracting the data
First I need to extract the title post and the posted date of the post
here's the url.

URL: https://cheddar.com/media/safety-concerns-over-teslas-autopilot-from-consumer-reports-as-wall-street-turns-bearish

Inside view-source there's a script in a json format that contains the data that I needed

Something like this, I crop the other text to minimize the space

```
<script>
      window.__RELAY_STORE__ = {"public_at":"2019-05-22T11:02:43- 
04:00","updated_at":"2019-05-22T15:25:20- 
04:00","thumbnail_attribution":null,"body":null,"title":"Safety Concerns 
Over Tesla's Autopilot from Consumer Reports as Wall Street Turns Bearish"
</script>
```

I just only need to get the "public_at" and the "title"

And What I have tried is this,

```
data = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'window.__RELAY_STORE__')]/text()")
#Locate the script

datatxt = data.extract_first()
#Extract the script

start = datatxt.find('client:') - 2
end = datatxt.find('window.__REDUX_STATE__')
# find start and end of data 

json_string = datatxt[start:end]
```

but when I load it or convert it to python dictionary

```
 data = json.loads(json_string)
```

I've got an error something like this

```
Extra data: line 1 column 27284 (char 27283)
```

Any idea how can I get those data please?

Comment: The json string is not valid json data. Maybe post the output of `print(json_string)` to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Yes that's why I am trying to make it a valid json string, and I've got this error "Extra data: line 1 column 27284 (char 27283)"

Comment: Look at the string and you'll see why it's not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get data in this way:

```
txt = response.xpath("//script[contains(., 'window.__RELAY_STORE__')]/text()").re_first('window.__RELAY_STORE__ = (.*);')
```

This will crop name of js-variable and last `;`. So then when I call `json.loads(txt)` it gives me valid json.