# Fetch page with Scrapy, execute JS and extract variable

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a project using the python screen-scraping framework `scrapy`. I created a spider that loads all `<script>` tags and processes the second one. This is because within the test data I gathered, the data I need, was in the second `<script>` tag.

But now I have a problem, whereas some pages contain the data I want in some other script tags (#3 or #4). Further obstacle is that mostly the second line of the second javascript tag has the JSON I want. But depending on the page, this could also be the 3rd or the 4th line.

Consider this simple HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            This is a text
        </p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myJSON = {
                a: "a",
                b: 42
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can access `myJSON.b` and get `42` if I open this page in my browser (firefox) and go to the developer tools and `console.log(myJSON.b)`
So my Question is: How can I extract JavaScript variable or JSON from a scrapy-fetched-page?

Comment: you would use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. OR outdated [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/). OR [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which has even plugin for Scrapy: [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

Comment: @furas I totally disagree. Selenium is above all a webtester, not a webcrawler. So it takes more time to load the page and for something useless because there are a lot of ways to extract json pattern without anything that scrapy. I mean by there I exclude scrapy-splash too.

Comment: duplicate of [How to extract data from javascript in a json format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56294152/10884791)

Answer (score 2):

I had run into a similar issue before and I solved it by extracting the text in the script tag using something like (based on your sample HTML file):

`response.xpath('//script/text()')`

After that I used a regular expression to extract the required data in JSON format. So, using the selector above and your sample HTML, something close to:

```
pattern = r'i-suck-at-regular-expressions'
json_data = response.xpath('//script/text()').re_first(pattern)
```

Next, you should be able to use the `json` library to load the data as a ***python dictionary*** like so:

```
json.loads(json_data)
```

And it should return something similar to:

```
{"a": "a", "b": 42}
```